# How do I concatenate strings repeatedly at compile time?

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I wrote the following code for using string in compile time:

```cpp
template<char... Chars>
struct CnstString {
    template<char... Aped>
    using push_back = CnstString<Chars..., Aped...>;
    constexpr static char value[] = {Chars...};
};
```

It's fine when I use it like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using str = CnstString<'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'>;
int main()
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0; // it will output "Hello"
}
```

What I want to do is use a recursive template struct, splice a string given by the above code at compile time, and append a `'\0'` to the array at the recursive end point.

The reason I wrote this code is because I want to concatenate a same string multiple times. Obviously I can't concatenate the same string together like `"Hello""Hello"`.

The recursive template struct is shown below:

```cpp
template<int N, typename Str>
struct RepeatStr {
    using ret = RepeatStr<N-1, Str>; // this is an error, I don't know how to pass parameters
};
template<typename Str>
struct RepeatStr<-1, Str> {
    using ret = Str:: template push_back<'\0'>;
};
```

However, I found that I didn't know how to append characters to itself using its characters in Str.

Is there something wrong? Or it's just impossible to do in compile time?

Comment: Always include error in your question.

Comment: >Obviously I can't concatenate the same string together like "Hello""Hello"
=>
You can though; the preprocessor will concatenate adjacent string literals. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yj9o8qasW)

Comment: What I mean is that I need to use a variable to specify the number of times the string is repeated, so I can't use literal concatenation directly.@AndyG

Comment: @Konvt See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/frb5hdT8a) after I added the `template` keyword before `push_back`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, I would change definition of `CnstString` to place '\0' only in `value`

```
template<char... Chars>
struct CnstString {
    constexpr static char value[] = {Chars..., '\0'};
};
```

Then provide `operator +` (which would allow Fold expression (C++17) later)

```
template <char... Cs1, char...Cs2>
CnstString<Cs1..., Cs2...> operator +(CnstString<Cs1...>, CnstString<Cs2...>) { return {}; }
```

Finally, you `RepeatStr<N, Str>` which would have a type for `Str{} + .. + Str{}`:

```
template<int N, typename Str>
struct RepeatStr {
    // C++20
    using ret = decltype([]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return ((static_cast<void>(Is), Str{}) + ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>()));
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h9ojbKT4Y)

As you are limited to C++14, replacing fold expression of C++17 by "recursive" function call:

```
template <typename T>
auto sum_impl(T t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto sum_impl(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    return t + sum_impl(ts...);
}
```

And replace the template lambda(C++20) by regular template function:

```
template <typename Str, std::size_t... Is>
auto repeat_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return sum_impl((static_cast<void>(Is), Str{})...);
}

template<int N, typename Str>
struct RepeatStr {
    using ret = decltype(repeat_impl<Str>(std::make_index_sequence<N>()));
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sn6bvE981)

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, may I ask if this code can be used in C++11 after modification?

Comment: For C++11, you have to implement std::index_sequence yourself. There are several posts on SO for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something wrong?

You need to add the keyword `template` in the using declaration to tell the compiler that `push_back` is used a template.

```
template<int N, typename Str>
struct RepeatStr {
    using ret = RepeatStr<N-1, Str>; 
};
template<typename Str>
struct RepeatStr<-1, Str> {
//--------------------vvvvvvvv------------------->works now
    using ret = Str:: template push_back<'\0'>;    
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Khfxz1dG8)